# WCF: async CTP: is it possible to use?

Tags: wcf, async-ctp

I am trying to use asyn CTP with WCF, but I have problems because Task is not serializable.

I have installed CTP v3.

Is it possible to use asyn CTP with WCF? is it need to configure something more than install only the CTP?

I am thinking that if is not possible to use async CTP jet, perhaps instead of using async CTP in the service side, I can implement async method with async CTP that call to the normal methods (not async methods) of the service. is this a good option? In this case the service does not implement async methods.

Other option is in the service side, implement the async methods with the begin/end methods, wrapping this two methods in a task using Task.Factory.FromAsync method. But this is more work.

So My question is, if I want that the client is not blocked while it waits for the service response, I can use two solutions. First use async CTP in the client that call normal methods of the service, or use async methods in the service using Task.Factory.FromAsync. Which is the best option? Why?

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about VS 2010 with Async CTP, but with VS 11 Beta (which you should probably use anyway), you can simply define an operation that returns a `Task`:

```
[OperationContract]
Task<string> GetData(int value);
```

And then implement it using `async`:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int value)
{
    return await …;
}
```

I would assume the same approach would work with Async CTP, but it's just an assumption.

Comment: If I use [OerationContract], I get the error that task is cannot be serializable, so perhaps CTP is not compatible with WCF in the VS2010.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. Why don't you try VS 11?

Comment: Well, VS 11 it's still a beta, so it's not an option in this case, it would be for a production application.

Comment: But CTP is even less than a beta. If you don't want to use something that's not production-quality, then you certainly shouldn't use Async CTP. Tha's why it's called Community Technology *Preview*.

Comment: Then I am wrong, because I think that CTP was the same version that I could get with the final version of VS 11. But I am wrong, I am studying the vs 11 option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve a non-blocking client call is on the client side, for two reasons:

1. Client side asynchronous methods can be generated by the existing VS tools
2. Passing Task over service boundary would require you write your own synchronization functionality.

To generate client-side Task<> based (and therefore async/await compatible) methods for a service:

1. In VS11, a new checkbox exists: "Generate Task-based methods" under "Allow generation of asynchronous operations" in the Configure Service Reference dialog. (I believe it is not yet documented)
2. For the CTP you can use the extension described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/efb6d66b-1ff1-43d2-893b-876c2e6aa1c1/) to generate Task based methods.